# Unseen C++ syntax

Tags: c++

A friend sent me this and I really don't know what it is, inside the loop. Whatever it be it calls the std::set constructor half million times.... any help appreciated. I would expect a compiler error, but it actually compiles in g++ 4.4 and 4.5 and the behavior is different to copy construction...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <set>
#include <string>

typedef boost::unordered_map<int, std::set<int> > mymap;

int main () {
    mymap map;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++ )     
    {
        std::set<int>  map[i] ;
    }
    return 1;
};
```

Comment: Code shouldn't even compile. What's your question?

Comment: In C++ use <cstdio> and <cstdlib>

Comment: It is a gcc extension that allows variable-length arrays (VLAs) in C++ (it is a standard feature of C99).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are dealing with a GCC-specific non-standard extension of C++ language. Each iteration defines an array of `std::map` objects with `i` elements (and immediately destroys it).

In standard C++ it is illegal to use a non-constant expression to specify array size, so the code is not legal C++. It compiles, again, only because GCC allows it as an extension.

Answer (score 1):

AndreyT already pretty much answered the question, but here's a more verbose definition:

> Variable-length automatic arrays are
>   allowed in ISO C99, and as an
>   extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode
>   and in C++. (However, GCC's
>   implementation of variable-length
>   arrays does not yet conform in detail
>   to the ISO C99 standard.) These arrays
>   are declared like any other automatic
>   arrays, but with a length that is not
>   a constant expression. The storage is
>   allocated at the point of declaration
>   and deallocated when the brace-level
>   is exited. For example:

```
 FILE *
 concat_fopen (char *s1, char *s2, char *mode)
 {
   char str[strlen (s1) + strlen (s2) + 1];
   strcpy (str, s1);
   strcat (str, s2);
   return fopen (str, mode);
 }
```

You shouldn't use VLAs (in C++) **OR** `alloca()` (as the GCC documentation suggests at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) as they are both considered pretty "meh" practice. They can both lead to stack overflows and/or undefined behavior.

**Edit**: reading the GCC documentation more closely and looking at

```
 int tester (int len, char data[len][len])
 {
   /* ... */
 }
```

.. I seriously hope no one writes code like that. I guess it's a cool feature, but still... wtf?

Answer (score 0):

The same code is

```
struct Foo {};

int main()
{
    int i = 100;
    Foo  map[i];
}
```

It's a declaration of variable "map" of type "array of Foo"; This array has a dynamic size i.

Comment: This shouldn't compile in c++. Some compilers may do it, but it's not exactly right.

Comment: @Josh @GMan unless it's a C99 VLAs used by GCC in C++ code. Compiling this with `-pedantic` gives me `warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'map'`.

Answer (score 0):

On iteration i of the loop, you create an array of i std::sets.  The total number created is thus i(i+1)/2 = 500500.

Comment: That's what it would do if it compiled ;)

Comment: I'm guessing he wanted to know why he had so many constructor calls.  At any rate, code that does essentially the same thing compiles for me (g++ 4.1.2 - but I don't have boost so I used a different typedef).

Answer (score -1):

I see the following compilation errors

```
alias g++
alias g++='g++ -ansi -pedantic -Wall -W -Wconversion -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings'

c.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
c.cpp:10: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘map’
c.cpp:10: warning: declaration of ‘map’ shadows a previous local
c.cpp:7: warning: shadowed declaration is here
c.cpp:10: warning: unused variable ‘map’
```

Comment: true; but I always compile with `-Werror` to treat warnings as errors :-)